# scrapy converting InitSpider to CrawlSpider w/ login

Tags: html, authentication, screen-scraping, scrapy

How can I convert this working example below into a crawlSpider and crawl in depth not just the first main page but in depth. This example works fine no errors but i want to use crawlspider instead of InitSpider and crawl deeeply. Thanks in advance

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders.init import InitSpider
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from linkedpy.items import LinkedpyItem

class LinkedPySpider(InitSpider):
    name = 'LinkedPy'
    allowed_domains = ['linkedin.com']
    login_page = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login'
    start_urls = ["http://www.linkedin.com/csearch/results"]

    def init_request(self):
    #"""This function is called before crawling starts."""
    return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

    def login(self, response):
    #"""Generate a login request."""
    return FormRequest.from_response(response,
            formdata={'session_key': 'xxxx@gmail.com', 'session_password': 'xxxxx'},
            callback=self.check_login_response)

    def check_login_response(self, response):
    #"""Check the response returned by a login request to see if we aresuccessfully logged in."""
    if "Sign Out" in response.body:
        self.log("\n\n\nSuccessfully logged in. Let's start crawling!\n\n\n")
        # Now the crawling can begin..

        return self.initialized() 

    else:
        self.log("\n\n\nFailed, Bad times :(\n\n\n")
        # Something went wrong, we couldn't log in, so nothing happens.

    def parse(self, response):
    self.log("\n\n\n We got data! \n\n\n")
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//ol[@id=\'result-set\']/li')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = LinkedpyItem()
        item['title'] = site.select('h2/a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = site.select('h2/a/@href').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

output

```
2013-07-11 15:50:01-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.16.5 started (bot: linkedpy)
2013-07-11 15:50:01-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetCon
sole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2013-07-11 15:50:01-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAut
hMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, De
faultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMi
ddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2013-07-11 15:50:01-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMi
ddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddle
ware
2013-07-11 15:50:01-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines:
2013-07-11 15:50:01-0500 [LinkedPy] INFO: Spider opened
2013-07-11 15:50:01-0500 [LinkedPy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scra
ped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2013-07-11 15:50:01-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:602
3
2013-07-11 15:50:01-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2013-07-11 15:50:02-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.linked
in.com/uas/login> (referer: None)
2013-07-11 15:50:02-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.
linkedin.com/nhome/> from <POST https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit>
2013-07-11 15:50:04-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.linkedi
n.com/nhome/> (referer: https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login)
2013-07-11 15:50:04-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG:


    Successfully logged in. Let's start crawling!



2013-07-11 15:50:05-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.linkedi
n.com/csearch/results> (referer: http://www.linkedin.com/nhome/)
2013-07-11 15:50:05-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG:


     We got data!



2013-07-11 15:50:05-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.linkedin
.com/csearch/results>
    {'link': [u'/companies/1009/IBM?trk=ncsrch_hits&goback=%2Efcs_*2_*2_fals
e_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2'],
     'title': [u'IBM']}
2013-07-11 15:50:05-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.linkedin
.com/csearch/results>
    {'link': [u'/companies/1033/Accenture?trk=ncsrch_hits&goback=%2Efcs_*2_*
2_false_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2'],
     'title': [u'Accenture']}
2013-07-11 15:50:05-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.linkedin
.com/csearch/results>
    {'link': [u'/companies/1038/Deloitte?trk=ncsrch_hits&goback=%2Efcs_*2_*2
_false_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2'],
     'title': [u'Deloitte']}
2013-07-11 15:50:05-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.linkedin
.com/csearch/results>
    {'link': [u'/companies/1035/Microsoft?trk=ncsrch_hits&goback=%2Efcs_*2_*
2_false_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2'],
     'title': [u'Microsoft']}
2013-07-11 15:50:05-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.linkedin
.com/csearch/results>
    {'link': [u'/companies/1025/Hewlett-Packard?trk=ncsrch_hits&goback=%2Efc
s_*2_*2_false_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2'],
     'title': [u'Hewlett-Packard']}
2013-07-11 15:50:05-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.linkedin
.com/csearch/results>
    {'link': [u'/companies/1028/Oracle?trk=ncsrch_hits&goback=%2Efcs_*2_*2_f
alse_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2'],
     'title': [u'Oracle']}
2013-07-11 15:50:05-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.linkedin
.com/csearch/results>
    {'link': [u'/companies/1093/Dell?trk=ncsrch_hits&goback=%2Efcs_*2_*2_fal
se_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2'],
     'title': [u'Dell']}
2013-07-11 15:50:05-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.linkedin
.com/csearch/results>
    {'link': [u'/companies/1123/Bank+of+America?trk=ncsrch_hits&goback=%2Efc
s_*2_*2_false_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2'],
     'title': [u'Bank of America']}
2013-07-11 15:50:05-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.linkedin
.com/csearch/results>
    {'link': [u'/companies/1015/GE?trk=ncsrch_hits&goback=%2Efcs_*2_*2_false
_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2'],
     'title': [u'GE']}
2013-07-11 15:50:05-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.linkedin
.com/csearch/results>
    {'link': [u'/companies/1441/Google?trk=ncsrch_hits&goback=%2Efcs_*2_*2_f
alse_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2'],
     'title': [u'Google']}
2013-07-11 15:50:05-0500 [LinkedPy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2013-07-11 15:50:05-0500 [LinkedPy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 2243,
     'downloader/request_count': 4,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
     'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 91349,
     'downloader/response_count': 4,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
     'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 11, 20, 50, 5, 177000),
     'item_scraped_count': 10,
     'log_count/DEBUG': 22,
     'log_count/INFO': 4,
     'request_depth_max': 2,
     'response_received_count': 3,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 11, 20, 50, 1, 649000)}
2013-07-11 15:50:05-0500 [LinkedPy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: How about you write some code to do it first and then if you have a question you ask it here?

Comment: @John I did write some code and posted a question but no one answer it [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578727/scrapy-log-into-a-site-and-do-a-crawlspider-but-no-working)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inherit from `CrawlSpider` and just override `start_requests` instead of `init_request`:

```
def start_requests(self):
    yield Request(
        url=self.login_page,
        callback=self.login,
        dont_filter=True
    )
```

`parse` is the method that `CrawlSpider` uses to actually crawl for links, so rename your `parse` method to something else.

Also, you can use generators instead of making a list:

```
def parse_page(self, response):
    self.log("\n\n\n We got data! \n\n\n")

    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//ol[@id=\'result-set\']/li')

    for site in sites:
        item = LinkedpyItem()
        item['title'] = site.select('./h2/a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = site.select('./h2/a/@href').extract()

        yield item
```